QGIS - SpatiaLite - Getting info from contained and nearest features
I’m working on QGIS with a SpatialLite DB (SQLite). I have four layers, and the fourth one (table: "ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY") is populated with the contents of two other layers (table: "ESPECES_PT" and table: "HABITATS_POLY"), depending on the information in the third layer (table: "ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS").
Here is what I’m trying to do:

"HABITATS_POLY" contains POLYGONS.
"ESPECES_PT" contains POINTS.
"ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY" contains POLYGONS.
"ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS" is a geometry less layer

When I set the value of the field "add_poly" in the table "ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS" to ‘Oui’, I want to:

Copy the polygon from the layer "HABITATS_POLY" to the layer "ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY" where the feature of "ESPECES_PT" (where "ESPECES_PT.nom_simple" = "ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS.nom_simple") is located inside or within a specified perimeter (defined by "distance" in the table "ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS").
In the field "nom_simple" (in the table "ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY"), list all species that are located within the distance specified in the "distance" field of the table "ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS".
In the field "pres_poly", list only the species ("nom_simple") that are located inside the polygon.
In the field "prox_poly", list only the species ("nom_simple") that are located outside but within the specified distance from the polygon.

Important: In this specific situation, only one copy of each polygon is allowed. Therefore, I want to list every entity located inside or within a defined distance from the polygon.
All is almost working, here is my code:
To add a feature:
   INSERT INTO ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY (
        Visibilite, 
        ESPECE, 
        nom_vernac, 
        id_rel, 
        geom, 
        SURF_EH, 
        presence, 
        COMPART, 
        Dval, 
        Tval, 
        Hval, 
        LIB_PHYSIO, 
        CAT_HAB, 
        ogc,
        pres_poly,
        prox_poly
    ) 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        'Oui', 
        '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}', 
        '{' || NEW.nom_vernac || '}', 
        HP.id, 
        HP.geom AS geom, 
        (ST_Area(HP.geom) / 10000) AS SURF_EH, 
        'Avérée', 
        NEW.compart, 
        NEW.delim, 
        '-', 
        NEW.habitat, 
        HP.LIB_PHYSIO, 
        HP.CAT_HAB, 
        HP.ogc_fid,
        CASE
            WHEN ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
        END AS pres_poly,
        CASE
            WHEN NOT ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
        END AS prox_poly
    FROM HABITATS_POLY HP 
    INNER JOIN ESPECES_PT EP 
        ON ST_Distance(HP.geom, EP.geom) <= NEW.distance 
    INNER JOIN ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS EH 
        ON EH.nom_simple = EP.nom_simple 
    WHERE
        NEW.add_poly = 'Oui'
        AND EP.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple 
        AND NEW.delim = 'Habitat' 
        AND INSTR(NEW.habitat, HP.CAT_HAB) > 0 
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY EHP 
            WHERE NEW.compart = EP.compartime 
            AND EHP.id_rel = HP.id
        );

To update a feature, when the polygon already exists in “ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY”
UPDATE ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY 
SET 
    ESPECE = COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.ESPECE, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.ESPECE) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}', 
    nom_vernac = COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.nom_vernac, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.nom_vernac) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_vernac || '}',
    pres_poly = 
        CASE WHEN ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN
            CASE WHEN pres_poly IS NULL OR pres_poly = '{}' THEN
                '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            ELSE
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            END
        ELSE
            ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly 
        END,
    prox_poly = 
        CASE WHEN NOT ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN
            CASE WHEN prox_poly IS NULL OR prox_poly = '{}' THEN 
                '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            ELSE    
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            END
        ELSE 
            ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly
        END 
FROM ESPECES_PT EP, HABITATS_POLY HP 
WHERE 
    ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.id_rel = HP.id 
    AND NEW.add_poly = 'Oui'
    AND ESPECE NOT LIKE '%' || NEW.nom_simple || '%' 
    AND compart = NEW.COMPART 
    AND NEW.delim = Dval 
    AND INSTR(NEW.habitat, HP.CAT_HAB) > 0 
    AND ST_Distance(HP.geom, EP.geom) <= NEW.distance;

There is a weird behavior in the fields ‘pres_poly’ and ‘prox_poly’ that I don’t understand. The values of “nom_simple” are not properly written in the corresponding fields.
In the example project, I’m sharing; you have 3 features in "ESPECES_PT". Among these 3 features, only 1 is contained within the polygon (In HABITATS_POLY where CAT_HAB ‘Boisements et forêts (milieux fermés)’*), while the others are near it (less than 120m). However, the field “pres_poly” contains 2 names, and “prox_poly” contains only 1 name (it should be the opposite).
To reproduce this behavior, you can simply go to "ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS" and change the field “add_poly” from ‘Non’ to ‘Oui’ (the field in green with checkboxes).
*Knowing this is not important. More importantly, there is only one polygon that is copied (which is good), but its content isn’t properly filled.
The part of the code where I have an issue is this one :
    pres_poly = 
        CASE WHEN ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN
            CASE WHEN pres_poly IS NULL OR pres_poly = '{}' THEN
                '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            ELSE
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            END
        ELSE
            ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly 
        END,
    prox_poly = 
        CASE WHEN NOT ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN
            CASE WHEN prox_poly IS NULL OR prox_poly = '{}' THEN 
                '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            ELSE    
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
            END
        ELSE 
            ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly
        END 
    --Lval = '-' 
FROM ESPECES_PT EP, HABITATS_POLY HP 
WHERE 
    ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.id_rel = HP.id 
    AND NEW.add_poly = 'Oui'
    AND ESPECE NOT LIKE '%' || NEW.nom_simple || '%' 
    AND compart = NEW.COMPART 
    AND NEW.delim = Dval 
    AND INSTR(NEW.habitat, HP.CAT_HAB) > 0 
    AND ST_Distance(HP.geom, EP.geom) <= NEW.distance;

EDIT: Forgot to add the test project I'm talking about.
Here is a link to download a sample project
https://fromsmash.com/test-project-sqlite

distinct
Names like Dval would be better as d_val.
Queries that start out as "only needing sqlite"
will sometimes migrate over to other DB vendors
who have different rules about case smashing.
Sixteen columns starts to sound like "a lot" of attributes,
but IDK maybe the design is good and we really do need them all.
However, it troubles me that I see no obvious
PK
in there. Every relation should have a PK.
For testing and expository purposes, maybe consider
boiling down queries to just the handful of attributes
that are really interesting or troublesome?
You may find it convenient to bury those CASE statements
within CREATE VIEW, so during debugging you have short simple queries.
This is much like repeatedly deleting and recreating a short
temp table during debugging, to help you focus on troublesome rows.
Simplifying may help you to sort out the {pres_poly, prox_poly} confusion.
    SELECT DISTINCT 

Ok, here's the big one.
Clearly this can be correct and performant.
But often a DISTINCT qualifier suggests lazy design,
and can interfere with interpreting SELECT EXPLAIN plan output.
It comes back to "what is the PK?".
Consider dropping the DISTINCT syntactic sugar
and spelling out your GROUP BY clauses explicitly.
This usually makes it easier to evaluate correctness,
to see PK relationships, to see "dirty data" uniqueness violations
in a table, and to figure out whether you have a sensible query plan.
each relation has a primary key
Rows that lack a PK are disorganized and
should just be lines in a text file.
When using a relational database, we're usually
trying to show that "name of row" maps to "several attributes".
Instead of an f(x) -> y mapping,
think of a table f as f(pk1) -> (a1, a2, ..., aN).
Sometimes we use a compound PK with multiple columns,
so we might see f(pk1, pk2) -> (a1, a2, ..., aN).
Now, I don't know what your various primary keys are --
you didn't tell me and I can't see them.
But commonly they appear as the first one or several columns,
and often letters like id or name will be part of the
identifier.
We write code to communicate with the machine,
but more importantly to communicate technical ideas
to collaborators. I was explaining that I was having
a hard time understanding what your relations mean,
and that possibly you are as well, which can be
exacerbated by tacking on a "quick fix" of DISTINCT
to a query. It can be a little harder to carefully
work out a proper GROUP BY clause, but typically the
intellectual effort invested is rewarded by a better
understanding and greater clarity of communication.
I'm not saying one has to go that route, but I
have often seen it prove helpful when my colleagues
adopt it.
Consider these two queries, about which nothing else is revealed:
SELECT          c1, c2, c3, c4 FROM ...
SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3, c4 FROM ...
The first admits of duplicates.
The second may produce fewer rows, but the only plausible PK
we could propose is all four columns (c1, c2, c3, c4).
We can't tell if a subset of those four is enough to
uniquely name a row. And we certainly can't tell
if contiguous columns on the left are a PK candidate,
followed by contiguous attribute columns on the right.
The machine does not impose such constraints,
but they can be helpful when communicating technical
ideas to humans.
OTOH, reveal the GROUP BY clause and I can tell you
the PK of the resulting relation.
Sometimes it corresponds to a PK seen in one of the JOINed
tables, and sometimes a query will induce a brand new PK.
name of PK
When in doubt, invent a brand new
synthetic
key and use that for JOINs:
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id  INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
  a_1 ... ,
  a_2 ... ,
  ...
  a_n ...
);

Suppose you wanted to use a
natural
key instead.
Then list it first, and draw it from the business domain.
If we were modeling a small neighborhood primary school,
we might try this:
CREATE TABLE student (
  name     TEXT  PRIMARY KEY,
  age      INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  address  TEXT,
  ...

But for even a school of modest size we will
soon encounter duplicate names, e.g. a John Smith
enrolled in one grade and another John Smith
enrolled in the next grade above.
At which point we abandon "natural" in favor
of a "synthetic" id.
Any large university would fill in the unique identifier
that appears on photo ID cards they issue.
Also, variant address spellings, such as
"12 E Crescent Ct" versus
"12 East Crescent Court"
will soon drive us crazy. So we might
normalize
in this way:
CREATE TABLE home (
  id       INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
  address  TEXT  NOT NULL,
  city     TEXT  NOT NULL,
  state    TEXT  NOT NULL,
  zip      TEXT  NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE student (
  id       INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
  name     TEXT  NOT NULL,
  home_id  INTEGER  REFERENCES home(id) ...
);

function disables index
    AND ESPECE NOT LIKE '%' || NEW.nom_simple || '%' 

If you need it, you need it, that's fine.
I will just note in passing that that conjunct doesn't let
the query planner exploit indexes on the ESPECE column.
Similar remarks for the INSTR() function when matching HP.CAT_HAB.
If you can arrange matters so AND ESPECE NOT LIKE NEW.nom_simple || '%'
is correct, then we can filter on such an index.

Alright, I will rename all my columns to avoid issues in other databases. The fact that I'm using uppercase is already confusing sometimes, as SQLite converts everything to lowercase.
Most of the columns are there to transfer information between tables, primarily as a reminder, for easy access to the information, and to help me not get lost in my queries, as it can be quite difficult to visualize sometimes. But eventually, later, I will reduce the number of columns.

Do you mean, I didn't use PK in the queries ? If yes, indeed, it didn't seem useful because PK is not updated when I update a field.
Isn't GROUP BY used to group rows that have the same values for the specified columns? It is practical when I need to regroup information, but in my situation, all the information is always located in the same row. So I don't know exactly how to proceed.
Regarding your last comment, maybe I can change it to this: SELECT (NEW.nom_simple) IN (ESPECE). Then I can work with the result, which will be either 0 or 1. Thank you !

As you recommended, I added the pk (or id / pkuid) values in my code (this is how I understand it) and worked on a small sample.
This indeed helped me understand some of my mistakes, and now the initial issue is resolved. The fields are properly completed.
pk's don't have the same name depending on the layers (another thing I should change).
"HABITATS_POLY" : id
"ESPECES_PT" : pkuid
"ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY" : pk
"ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS" : pk
Now, when a polygon is added in ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY, its "id" is saved in "pk_poly"
And the list of corresponding "pkuid" of "ESPECES_PT" are stored in "pk_pt"
Here is the code I'm using for now:
CREATE TRIGGER updt_hab 
AFTER UPDATE OF add_poly, habitat, distance ON ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY (
        pk_pt,
        pk_poly,
        Visibilite, 
        ESPECE, 
        nom_vernac, 
        id_rel, 
        geom, 
        SURF_EH, 
        presence, 
        COMPART, 
        Dval, 
        Tval, 
        Hval, 
        --Lval, 
        LIB_PHYSIO, 
        CAT_HAB, 
        ogc,
        pres_poly,
        prox_poly
    ) 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        EP.pkuid,
        HP.id, 
        'Oui', 
        NEW.nom_simple, -- '{' ||  || '}', 
        NEW.nom_vernac, -- '{' ||  || '}', 
        HP.id, 
        HP.geom AS geom, 
        (ST_Area(HP.geom) / 10000) AS SURF_EH, 
        'Avérée', 
        NEW.compart, 
        NEW.delim, 
        '-', 
        NEW.habitat, 
        --NEW.distance, 
        HP.LIB_PHYSIO, 
        HP.CAT_HAB, 
        HP.ogc_fid,
        CASE
            WHEN ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
        END AS pres_poly,
        CASE
            WHEN NOT ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
        END AS prox_poly
    FROM HABITATS_POLY HP 
    INNER JOIN ESPECES_PT EP 
        ON ST_Distance(HP.geom, EP.geom) <= NEW.distance 
    INNER JOIN ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS EH 
        ON EH.nom_simple = EP.nom_simple 
    WHERE
        pk = NEW.pk 
        AND NEW.add_poly = 'Oui'
        AND EP.nom_simple = NEW.nom_simple 
        AND NEW.delim = 'Habitat' 
        AND HP.CAT_HAB IN (NEW.habitat)
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY EHP 
            WHERE NEW.compart = EP.compartime 
            AND EHP.id_rel = HP.id
        );

UPDATE ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY 
SET 
    pk_pt = pk_pt || ',' || EP.pkuid,
    ESPECE = ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.ESPECE || ',' || NEW.nom_simple, 
    nom_vernac = ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.nom_vernac || ',' || NEW.nom_vernac, 
    pres_poly = 
        CASE 
            WHEN ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN pres_poly IS NULL OR pres_poly = '{}' THEN
                        '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
                    ELSE
                        COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
                END
            ELSE
                ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.pres_poly 
        END,
    prox_poly = 
        CASE 
            WHEN NOT ST_Contains(HP.geom, EP.geom) THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN prox_poly IS NULL OR prox_poly = '{}' THEN 
                        '{' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
                    ELSE    
                        COALESCE(NULLIF(substr(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly, 1, length(ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly) - 1), ''), '') || ',' || NEW.nom_simple || '}'
                END
            ELSE 
                ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.prox_poly
        END 
    FROM ESPECES_PT EP
    JOIN HABITATS_POLY HP 
        ON ST_Distance(HP.geom, EP.geom) <= NEW.distance
    JOIN ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS EHA 
        ON EHA.nom_simple = EP.nom_simple
    WHERE 
        EHA.pk = NEW.pk
        AND ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.id_rel = HP.id 
        AND NEW.add_poly = 'Oui'
        AND NOT NEW.nom_simple IN (ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.ESPECE)
        AND ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY.compart = NEW.COMPART 
        AND NEW.delim = Dval 
        AND HP.CAT_HAB IN (NEW.habitat)
        AND ST_Distance(HP.geom, EP.geom) <= NEW.distance; 
END;

But now I feel like it is not properly coded. I've never been to a "programming school" and learned SQLite by trying things out. Some of the things you are explaining are probably basics, but they remain quite obscure to me right now.
I will try to work with GROUP BY if I figure out how to use it in my case.
I've added a test project, in any case you want to see the behavior of the initial issue.
And here is the new working test_project: the working one

I had to stick with the "INSTR(" function as IN can only be used in lists of values.

Good, good, you're making progress! I don't especially recommend putting the letters "pk" in a column identifier. Prefer "id", especially if you're using a synthetic int key. If I could offer you a "don't even think about it" rule of thumb, I guess I would encourage you to always make the first line of your CREATE TABLE statements be id  INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
